# Same application, different xml to be returned in case of error

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have an application that returns an xml like the following. Abridged version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Name>Bingo</Name> 
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Bongo</Name>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

It is validated by the client against an XSD.

But in case of error, it is returning a string instead of an xml. I want to make this uniform and always return an xml. However I don't want to change the XSD in order to add an error tag.

So, what is the right way of doing that?

I was thinking about different solutions:

1) Using different schema validation in case of error. But in that case how does the client know which xsd to use for the validation?

2) Don't use any xsd in case of error. But again, how does the client know if the xsd should be used or not?

3) Returning a json, where one of the parameters is an xml. In the json I can add an error message and a status response.

What's the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

It's understandable not to want to pollute your domain XSD with communication or application concerns such as `<Error/>` elements.

What's common instead is to have separate XSDs for those two concerns:  One for the domain, and a wrapper that covers communication matters.

This approach will work better than introducing strings or JSON separately to handle errors.

Also, be sure to set the HTTP return code of the response responsibly.